# Area between the curves $x=(5/3)y$ and $x=\sqrt{1+y^2}$

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

$x=(5/3)y$

$x=\sqrt{1+y^2}$

Set up and evaluate an integral expression with respect to y that give the area of S.

S is the area between these 2 curves and the axes. I have already found the point of intersection to be (5/4,3/4) and I have set up this expression:

$S=\int_0^.75 5/3ydy - \int_0^.75\sqrt{1+y^2}dy$

(Cant figure out the formatting on that sqrt but its the expression above)

I do not know how to solve the integral on the right.

Comment: Hint: Use trigonometric substitution.

Comment: If you don't mind offering a more specific hint I'd appreciate it, I'm trying to help my little sister during a meltdown. It's been years since I've dealt with this material.

Answer (score 1):

In a first year calculus course, symbolab is your best friend.

http://symbolab.com/math/search/%5Cint_%7B0%7D%5E%7B0.75%7D%5Csqrt%7B1%2By%5E%7B2%7D%7Ddy/?origin=button

Comment: this seems a bit complex for high school math..

Comment: I wouldn't have been able to do this integral in high school.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe not the easiest way, but here is how I did it.

Let $y = \sinh x$, remembering $\sinh x \equiv {1\over 2}(e^x - e^{-x})$ and $\cosh x \equiv {1\over 2}(e^x + e^{-x})$ so that $\cosh^2 x - \sinh^2 x = 1$.

Now with $y = \sinh x$ we find $dy = \cosh x\ dx$.

So the integral we are trying to evaluate is $\int{\cosh^2 x\ dx}$.

Note $\cosh^2 x = {1\over 4}(e^x+e^{-x})^2 = {1\over 2} + {1\over 4}(e^{2x} + e^{-2x})$, which is easily integrated with respect to $x$:

$$\int{\cosh^2 x\ dx} = \int{\left[{1\over 2} + {1\over 4}(e^{2x} + e^{-2x})\right]\ dx} = {x\over 2} + {1\over 8}(e^{2x}-e^{-2x})\,.$$

The exponentials can be rewritten as ${1\over 2}\sinh x\cosh x$. Thus

$$\int{\cosh^2 x\ dx} = {x\over 2} + {1\over 2}\sinh x\cosh x.$$

Remembering that $\cosh^2 x - \sinh^2 x = 1$, we have

$$\int{\cosh^2 x\ dx} = {x\over 2} + {1\over 2}\sinh x\sqrt{1+\sinh^2 x}.$$

In terms of $y$, this is $$\int{\sqrt{1+y^2}\,dy} = {1\over 2}\left(\sinh^{-1}y + y\sqrt{1+y^2}\right)\,.$$

Comment: This is WAY too complex for such a simple integral!

Comment: Well, it has the virtue of being correct. I don't think your answer from before is.

Comment: "Complex" seems to be a bit of an overstatement.  These may be functions that a high school student is not familiar with, but a calculus student should have at least _seen_ hyperbolic sinusoids at some point.  Either way, when a concept can be completely defined and explained in 1 short post, it can hardly be called simpler can it?  Anyway, "unfamiliar" isn't the same as "complex".